# Connect codeigniter with polymer

Tags: codeigniter, polymer

How to intergrate codeigniter and polymer  I have kept the webcomponentsjs folder in veiws page and index.html but it is not working. Can any one tell me the solution for integrating codeigniter and polymer

Answer (score 0):

Generally CI and Polymer should be two separate apps; Polymer as frontend app making AJAX calls to the backend CI APIs.

But also you can use Polymer elements inside CI views, just paste this code inside some CI view and it should work: [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/pXk9e48QByEkGmRJP1zs?p=preview)

```
...
<paper-textarea 
    label="textarea label"
    on-change="textarea_change"
></paper-textarea>
...
```